# How to Login to Google Play Store using Curl and Php?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get login to Google Play Store using curl, and 
i am using the following code:

**It is giving me 405 error,**

please take a look and let me know where i am wrong,

```
<?php

$USERNAME = 'some@gmail.com';
$PASSWORD = 'some_password';
$COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=androiddeveloper&continue=http://play.google.com/apps/publish');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$formFields = getFormFields($data);

$formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
$formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

$post_string = '';
foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (strpos($result, '<title>Redirecting') === false) {
    die("Login failed");
    var_dump($result);
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://play.google.com/apps/publish/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);
}

function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help to achive your target: Google recommends to use the gsutil to download reports from play store.

Download & export monthly reports
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en

Download sales & payout reports
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017?hl=en